# Thingsboard with mysql

Tags: thingsboard

I wonder if Thingsboard can work with MySQL?
I tried to modify the PostgreSQL DAO Configuration in thingsboard.yml file, but it doesnt work. The installation fail.

```
spring:
  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        enabled: "true"
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: "validate"
    database-platform: "${SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect}"
  datasource:
    driverClassName: "${SPRING_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME:org.mysql.jdbc.Driver}"
    url: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost/thingsboard}"
    username: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:root}"
    password: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:pw}"
```

Comment: we don't test this configuration. if it fails, the resolution of the issue is most likely trivial.

Answer (score 2):

- make changes in thingsboard.yml 'DAO Configuration' section (maybe you need to add mysql port also).
- review schema.sql and system-data.sql scripts to support MySQL dialect.

this pull request  : https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/pull/904
can helps

Answer (score 0):

${SPRING_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME:org.mysql.jdbc.Driver} mean   answer = SPRING_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME!=null ? SPRING_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME : org.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is currently not supported. We use hierarchical queries (a feature of PostgreSQL) for some specific requests. Migration is possible but will require code changes.